# count distinct group by day

Tags: sql, oracle

I've this subquery results:

```
DATE        REGCODE  REGCODE2    REGCODE 3   REGCODE4    
02/01/15    70771      5            6           8
02/01/15    null       5            21          8  
02/01/15    70855      4            5           13  
02/01/15    null       ...         ...          ...
03/01/15    70771
03/01/15    70772
05/01/15    null
05/01/15    70855
05/01/15    70826
```

and i need to Count the different `REGCODEs` grouping by date, but if one of them is repeated in one of the PREVIOUS dates, this none don´t count anymore

so, i need something like that:

```
DATE          COUNT(REGCODE)
02/01/15           2
03/01/15           1
05/01/15           1
```

Thank u very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.date, COUNT(DISTINCT t.regcode)
FROM yourtable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM yourtable prev
   WHERE prev.regcode=t.regcode
   AND prev.date<t.date
)
GROUP BY t.date;
```

(may need an index on regcode, date)

Comment: sorry, whats the meaning of SELECT 1?

Comment: Its an SQL compliant way of saying SELECT ANYTHING

Comment: It adds regs that have just repeated in any previous reg

Comment: Well, sorry, the thing is that i dont have only one column of REGCODE, I have 4, REGCODE1, REGCODE2, etc...

Comment: I have this table:                                                                                     DATE        REGCODE   REGCODE2     REGCODE3    REGCODE4    
02/01/15    70771              70007               70008              66558
02/01/15    null                   70007               55577             88777 
02/01/15    70855                NULL                  NULL            NULL     
02/01/15    null                     .....                        .....                ......
03/01/15    70771
03/01/15    70772
05/01/15    null
05/01/15    70855
05/01/15    70826

Comment: I dont know how to edit the table to post it in a beautiful way

Comment: I didnt ask about that structure in the first place because i was doing tests with only one column and i forgot the others. Sorry.

Comment: @Madmartigan - maybe you should ask a new question with your changed requirements then, as this answered what you originally asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its using `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PARTITION BY` with `REGCODE`.

```
declare @table table ([DATE] date, REGCODE int)

insert into @table
select '02/01/15', 70771 union
select '02/01/15', null union
select '02/01/15', 70855 union
select '02/01/15', null union
select '03/01/15', 70771 union
select '03/01/15', 70772 union
select '03/01/15', null union
select '05/01/15', 70855 union
select '05/01/15', 70826

select [DATE], COUNT([DATE]) from 
(
    select [DATE], REGCODE, 
    row_number() over (partition by  REGCODE order by [DATE]) rn 
    from @table 
) e 
where rn = 1 and regcode is not null
group by [DATE]
```

Comment: This isn't Oracle syntax.